# VBA to Auto select a range from a manually selected start position

Tags: excel, vba

OK Gurus I haven’t bugged anyone in months and I’m enjoying the learning experience but this one has me stumped.

I am creating candle stick charts for my own analysis from a large currency dataset.
I locate a specific starting date and time down to the minuted and highlight 5 rows across for example Range(A1:E1)  containing the following data Date&Time, Open, High, Low, Close

So I now have A1:E1 selected.

The starting range could be anywhere but the finish point is always 90 rows lower from that initial location. So I select that range manually by shift + page down until I highlight the required data.
Example Rang(A1:E90)

I do this manually every time many times. I have automated the copy and paste to specific target locations thanks to what I have learned but the above process has me stumped.

I have looked here for possible answers and have watched hours of youtube vba videos and google questions s to no avail. I have come up with some of my own clunky workarounds but this should be easy with code? 
I have attempted to do so by recording the process which simply gives me the range and not how it was achieved.

None of my code is of any use as I'm clueless as to how to achieve it. I am currently copying incorrect sized data into a named array and then simply referencing the array to the chart area but surely there's an elegant solution? I will include a screen shot showing a selected area from the type of data I am dealing with.

So, question. How do I select a range say A1 to E1 and then have vba select down a specified number of rows so that the selection is now the full range of data I want.[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub SelectStuff
selection.resize(selection.rows.count+90)
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Harassed Dad. Cool name! I ran this but got run-time error Object doesn't support this property or method.  I'm currently reading some pages on the selection resize property so you have greatly assisted and pointed me in the correct direction. If I cannot nut it out Ill come back and try again. Thanks for the pointer. :)

Comment: `Selection.Resize(Selection.Rows.Count + 90).Select` or  `Selection.Resize(90).Select` (relative/absolute)

Comment: Thank you Harassed Dad and KekuSemu. I did manage to work out the missing (selection) from the Microsoft dev site examples so I learned something. I have already incorporated this and assigned it to a few buttons so it has saved me hours of manual hunting and pecking. Thank you both again. Kindest regards. :)